# get JSON value using for loop android

Tags: android, json, for-loop

hi guys i want help to get `value` obj in JSON data

```
[
 { 
 "type": "visitors",
 "dates": [
     {
      "date": "2015-05-01",
      "items": [
           {
            "value": "100"
           }
        ]
      }
  ]
},
{
  "type": "actions",
  "dates": [
        {
         "date": "2015-05-01",
         "items": [
              {
               "value": "230"
              }
          ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "type": "actions-average",
  "dates": [
       {
        "date": "2015-05-01",
        "items": [
             {
              "value": "2.3"
             }
          ]
        }
       ]
    }
 ]
```

im using this code for getting `value` but i want assign different `value` to different variable

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String value = null;
        JSONArray datesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dates");
        for (int j = 0; j < datesArray.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject dates = datesArray.getJSONObject(j);
            JSONArray itemsArray = dates.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int k = 0; k < itemsArray.length(); k++) {
                JSONObject vvObj = itemsArray.getJSONObject(k);
                value = vvObj.getString("value");
                //Log.v(TAG, "Edited JSONData: " + k + value);
            }
        }
        values[i] = value;
        //Log.v(TAG, "loop JSONData: " + Arrays.toString(values));
    }
```

final result look like this

`var1 = value // form the first loop`

`var2 = value // form the 2nd loop`

`var3 = value // form the 3rd loop`

Comment: what problem u are getting using current code?

Comment: im getting `value` but i want to assign a different variable for each time loops like 1st loop value assign to `var1`, 2nd loop value  assign to `var2` like that

Comment: you are storing all values inside `values` then read from `values` and assign to other variables like var1=values[0],var2=values[1],... then what is issue?

Comment: Are the values you need coming in the values-array as seen in the code. You could assign to the variables you need after the for loop ends by taking values from the array

Comment: @Msk i getting `value` from for loop but i want assign to different variables its just example im showing up there in my app im getting more 10 `JSONObject` like that and i want to assign to different variables

Comment: values[i] = value; should be inside the nested for loops, just below value = vvObj.getString("value");. Once you come out of all loops, just assign to whatever variables you need, values from the array values[]

Comment: I eddited my code look at last part i showd you how to get back the values ,they are assigned one by one to the variable output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this . you put 'values[i]= value' in wrong place .It will get all values from all arrays. If you need different justa sk and I'll modify it.

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
{
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String value = null;
            JSONArray datesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dates");

            for (int j = 0; j < datesArray.length(); j++) 
             {
                JSONObject dates = datesArray.getJSONObject(j);

                JSONArray itemsArray = dates.getJSONArray("items");

                 for (int k = 0; k < itemsArray.length(); k++) 
                    {
                      JSONObject vvObj = itemsArray.getJSONObject(k);

                      values.add( vvObj.getString("value") );
                    }


             }

}

//check this part how to get back your data          
String output ;

for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) 
{
    output = values.get(i) ;

    //do something with value from possition i , is stored in output
    Log.v(TAG, "loop JSONData: " + output );
}
```

Comment: that helps but how to assign to different variables like `var1 = first loop value`, `var2 = 2nd loop value` etc

Comment: if you do values.get(i) you get the value from position i .Ex values.get(0) = 100 .Or you want to extract also "2015-05-01" ? You do not need to assign them not another variables , just use  values.get(5) if you need the value from posittion 6 etc .You count from 0. You dnrt need to do String a= values.get(5)

Comment: You can not create variables names 'var1' 'var2' while running your program.You define variables only when you write the program (ex String str) , not when program is running

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help

```
String[] values=new String[jsonArray.length()];
//create string array of size == jsonArray.length() outside of forloop

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    //String value = null;//comment this line
    JSONArray datesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dates");
    for (int j = 0; j < datesArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject dates = datesArray.getJSONObject(j);
        JSONArray itemsArray = dates.getJSONArray("items");
        for (int k = 0; k < itemsArray.length(); k++) {
            JSONObject vvObj = itemsArray.getJSONObject(k);
            value = vvObj.getString("value");
            //Log.v(TAG, "Edited JSONData: " + k + value);
        }
    }
    values[i] = value;
    //Log.v(TAG, "loop JSONData: " + Arrays.toString(values));
}
```